# Best way to manually commit after processing message on kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

I've been having some trouble with auto commit on Kafka consumer. I've decided to go ahead and manually commit the offset since the processing time of a message is variable. I'm using [kafka-python](https://pypi.org/project/kafka-python/) library and there is a `commit()` method but do I need to pass in any parameters? This is what I think it will look like, but not sure if this is the correct way to do it or if I am missing anything. The main reason why I want to commit the offset manually is because there are duplicate messages causing a lot of issues. I've provided what I have currently and what I think will be the solution.

Currently

```
            consumer = KafkaConsumer(
                bootstrap_servers=[...],
                auto_offset_reset='earliest',
                enable_auto_commit=True,
                group_id='my-client-id',
                max_poll_records=1,
                max_poll_interval_ms=180000,
                api_version=(2, 2, 1))
            consumer.subscribe([....])
            while not self.stop_event.is_set():
                for message in consumer:
                    try:
                        my_func(message.value)
                    except Exception as err:
                        raise err
```

Propose

- Do I need to include the `max_poll_records` or `max_poll_interval_ms` when I set `enable_auto_commit` to false?

```
            consumer = KafkaConsumer(
                bootstrap_servers=[...],
                auto_offset_reset='earliest',
                enable_auto_commit=False,
                group_id='my-client-id', # Don't need this
                max_poll_records=1,
                max_poll_interval_ms=180000,
                api_version=(2, 2, 1))
            consumer.subscribe([....])
            while not self.stop_event.is_set():
                for message in consumer:
                    try:
                        my_func(message.value)
                        consumer.commit() # New line
                    except Exception as err:
                        raise err
```

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need to include the max_poll_records or max_poll_interval_ms when
> I set enable_auto_commit to false?

`enable_auto_commit` is independent of other 2 configuration parameters. Refer [here](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#max.poll.interval.ms) to understand what is other 2 parameters are. So you can decide as per need you want to use those parameters. I recommend to keep them irrespective of auto_commit enabled or not.

I think, you have to pass the offset within `commit()` call when you disable the auto_commit, please refer [here](https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/_modules/kafka/consumer/group.html#KafkaConsumer.commit):

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that out - if I call `.commit()` is that enough to handle the manual commit process? I only have 1 partition for the group

Comment: @joethemow Edited the answer